# How get a detail of an array result

Tags: php, arrays

I don't know how to do this in PHP so I i'll ask it here.
Right now I have this:

```
$s3 = $sdk->getUser();
var_dump($s3["custom_fields"]);
```

It results in:

```
string(51) "a:1:{s:3:"IGN";s:27:"hfsdkklsdhfasfhoihgoiahgoid";}"
```

The only thing I want is: hfsdkklsdhfasfhoihgoiahgoid

How can I get that?

Comment: Google `unserialize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a serialized array.

```
var_dump(unserialize($s3["custom_fields"]));
```

there ya go.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
$s3 = $sdk->getUser();
$custom_fields = unserialize($s3["custom_fields"]);

echo $custom_fields['IGN'];
```